# How to select value form the drop down using python and selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[image: Here is the HTML code for the dropdown box]

[image: Here is dropdown box and i need to slect Albania from the drop down]

Here is the code I tried:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div""")
Select(dropdown).select_by_visible_text("Algeria")
```

Error : Select only workon select elements and not Div element .

Thank you for your help  !

Comment: This looks more like a "fake" select made with ul / li and styled to look like a combo box. You can try simulating a click on the `<li>` element that you want to select and see how that goes

Comment: Thank you ! Searched for li and it worked  lists = dropdown.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")